# Representing expiring records

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to store tariffs connected to a port.
So, the table can look like this:

```
create table tariffs(
    int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    price decimal(12,2),
    expiry bigint(11)
)
```

`expiry` represents a timestamp when that particular tariff will expire.
So I might have data like this:

```
id | price    | expiry
1  | 11.00    | 30/Jan/2022
2  | 12.00    | 30/Feb/2022
3  | 13.00    | 30/Mar/2022
4  | 14.00    | 30/Apr/2022
5  | 15.00    | null
```

In this case, ID 5 isn't expired yet, meaning that it's current.
(I realise I put dates, there, rather than timestamps; I did so that it's easier to read)

The problem I have is in the logic to figure out which tariff to use given a specific date.
In an ideal world, if 5 were "Infinite", I could just do `WHERE expiry > date_apply limit 1` -- however, I don't have that luxury since `date_apply` won't be returned at all.

I COULD assign a very big number to `expiry` for the "current" entry. It would make the query work regardless. But... it feels wrong.

Somebody recommended using TWO fields for each tariff, a "from" and a "to", telling me that otherwise querying will be a nightmare. I am beginning to see what they mean... but then I fear operators might unwillingly have "holes" in the timeframes for tariffs, which would be difficult to prevent.

How should I organise my table, and how should I query it? What's the best practices here?

Comment: I would prefer to use from-to dates and for open period use date like '9999-12-31'

Comment: you can start by setting your expiry column as a date data-type rather than a timestamp.  And you only need one column because the SQL can check for other earlier or later values in the same column....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.price, t1.price) AS price
FROM (SELECT price FROM tariffs WHERE expiry IS NULL LIMIT 1) AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT price FROM tariffs WHERE expiry > ? ORDER BY expiry DESC LIMIT 1) AS t2
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wykqR5X7B9S424AWkA4aQy/1

The first subquery is bound to return 1 row if you have at least one unexpired tariff.

The second subquery may not return 1 row, if you put in a date too late. So I change this join to LEFT OUTER JOIN. If there is no matching row for the condition on expiry, the subquery will return no rows, and the outer join will replace these with NULLs.

So if `t2.*` is NULL, then the COALESCE() defaults to the unexpired value in `t1.price`.

Comment: Good point, I have edited my answer and realized I had a bug anyway. :)

Comment: Doesn't the query need an ORDER BY statement to make sure you actually get the latest possible tariff?

Comment: It was not clear to me that you wanted the latest tariff. I have edited the answer and the dbfiddle to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the ultimate price with an expiry null and we can use coalesce to assign a value according to the logic needed at the time.
Here we start with only an expired tarif and the expiry = *null* tarif. We create a view that gives us the expiry as `undefined`. We then add a tarif which is valid and it is correctly returned by the same view.

> ```
> create table tariffs(
>     id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     price decimal(12,2),
>     expiry date);
> insert into tariffs (price,expiry) values (11,'2022-01-30'),(12,null);
> ```

> ```
> create view current_tarif as
> select id, price, coalesce(expiry,'undefined') expiry
> from tariffs
> where coalesce(expiry,'3000-12-31') > curdate() 
> order by coalesce(expiry,'3000-12-31')
> limit 1;
> ```

> ```
> select * from current_tarif;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | price | expiry   
> -: | ----: | :--------
>  2 | 12.00 | undefined
> ```

> ```
> insert into tariffs (price,expiry) values (15,'2022-12-30');
> ```

> ```
> select * from current_tarif;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | price | expiry    
> -: | ----: | :---------
>  3 | 15.00 | 2022-12-30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c626f3874c307ce373e29f8707113ad)*

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using views? I would much prefer the solution to be one query. Can I create a subset and then query that on the fly?

Comment: Is something like this totally horrific? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b33d78d570d9ba1511ab5538efa1820

SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *, COALESCE(expiry, 2051273200) as expiry2 FROM tariffs) as temp 
WHERE 1648594700 < temp.expiry2
ORDER BY expiry2
LIMIT 1

Comment: You can use the same query as is in the view on it's own. Just remove the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Build your validity and expiry dates/timestamps as you go, using OLAP functions.

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
indata(id,price,expiry) AS (
          SELECT 1,11.00,DATE '30-Jan-2022'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,12.00,DATE '28-Feb-2022'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,13.00,DATE '30-Mar-2022'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,14.00,DATE '30-Apr-2022'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,15.00,NULL
)
,
enriched AS (
  SELECT 
    id
  , price
  , LAG(NVL(expiry, '9999-12-31'),1,'0001-01-01') OVER(ORDER BY id)  AS   validity
  , NVL(expiry, '9999-12-31')                    AS expiry
  FROM indata
  -- chk  id | price |  validity  |   expiry   
  -- chk ----+-------+------------+------------
  -- chk   1 | 11.00 | 0001-01-01 | 2022-01-30
  -- chk   2 | 12.00 | 2022-01-30 | 2022-02-28
  -- chk   3 | 13.00 | 2022-02-28 | 2022-03-30
  -- chk   4 | 14.00 | 2022-03-30 | 2022-04-30
  -- chk   5 | 15.00 | 2022-04-30 | 9999-12-31
)
SELECT
  price
FROM enriched
WHERE '2022-04-22' >= validity
  AND '2022-04-22  < expiry
;
```

Comment: Note `NVL()` is an Oracle function. The standard equivalent supported by MySQL is `COALESCE()`.

Comment: You're right that `NVL()` is not understood by MySQL. `COALESCE()`, however, is a multi-parameter function that returns the first non-NULL parameter, while `NVL()` and its synonyms `IFNULL()` and `ISNULL()` are two-parameter functions returning the second parameter if the first is NULL. Fixed-list parameter functions are a trifle more efficient than variable-list parameter functions. Try `IFNULL()`- that one works - as I do here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4e9859ae6818fe58d62729fe201ae18.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `CASE WHEN` statement and change the `expiry` column to max value 999-12-31(253402270022) if `expiry is null` then sort and get max expiry. Then you can execute the condition `expiry > date_apply`

```
WITH maxTariffs AS
(SELECT  id, 
  (CASE
    WHEN expiry IS NULL 
        THEN 253402270022
    ELSE expiry    
END) AS expiry
FROM tariffs)   
 
SELECT * FROM tariffs WHERE  id IN (SELECT id FROM maxTariffs WHERE expiry > DATE_APPLY ORDER BY expiry ASC )  LIMIT 1
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38c0aa4bedc2e05aa14c9f8784f59076)

Comment: This is the most readable solution. Is performance as good as COALESCE() ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to give out the correct answer though. If I try a query against the 16th of March ( 1647408000) I should get the row wit ID 3 (the latest tariff at that time)

Comment: @Merc I thought that you need to get the maximum allowable value. I changed the answer and now you will get the closest value in relation to DATE_APPLY. Try it, it might solve your problem)